# VS2015 Unit test project is unable to find a method

Tags: c#, debugging, testing, visual-studio-2015, method-missing

I'm getting this error:

> Result StackTrace:    at
>   UnitTestProject.ControllerTest.TestMethodQuoteEndCustomerSearch()
>   Result Message:    Test method
>   UnitTestProject.ControllerTest.TestMethodQuoteEndCustomerSearch threw
>   exception:  System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   QuoteCenter.Controllers.ECSearchController.QuoteEndCustomerSearch(System.String,
>   System.String, System.String, System.String)'.

My Test class looks like this:

```
namespace UnitTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ControllerTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethodQuoteEndCustomerSearch()
        {
        //arrange
        ECSearchController myController = new ECSearchController();           

        //ISSUE WITH THE NEXT LINE
        ViewResult result = myController .QuoteEndCustomerSearch("", "", "", "") as ViewResult;
        }
    }
}
```

The intellisense knows that myController has a method QuoteEndCustomerSearch.  But when I debug I get the above error.

The controller's method looks like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult QuoteEndCustomerSearch(String quoteId, String CID, String URL, String UserID)
    { 
        //...
        return View("QuoteEndCustomerSearch", model);
    }
```

Any tips on what else I should try to get it working?  I'm in Admin mode and I've restarted VS2015.

Comment: if the view has the same name as the action then there is no need to inclide it in `View()`. Change `return View("QuoteEndCustomerSearch", model);` to return View(model);

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip Nkosi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that my existing project had mvc version 5 but the new test project had a newer version.  All good now.
I didn't notice when I was using Nuget that the versions were different.
I think now is a good time for me to update all projects to the newest version of MVC.